# XCode 12 cropping branch names

Tags: version-control, xcode12

This is a change i don't understand - and i'd like to revert. Since i installed XCode 12, it is cropping my branch names and it drives me crazy. I did not find an option to change that back to full readability - any ideas?

[image]

Comment: This is probably an XCode bug. I have reported it and hopefully it will be fixed in the upcoming version.